# Alamofire v4 extra argument method in call error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

Once I updated to alamofire version 4 I get the error: **extra argument method in call**

```
Alamofire.request("www.blabla", method: .put, parameters: parameters, headers: headers, encoding: .JSON)
```

I already changed it to use "method: .put" like above but I still get the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue upgrading to Alamofire 4 and solved it by moving the headers argument and making it the last argument in the call. Also `encoding: .JSON` should be `encoding: JSONEncoding.default`.

Call should look like this:

```
Alamofire.request(url: myUrl, method: .put, parameters: myParams,
     encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: myHeaders)
```

Comment: I tried to switch it to: Alamofire.request(url: "www.blabla", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers) but I still get the error : /

Comment: For encoding, replace `.JSON` with `JSONEncoding.default`. Original answer updated.

Comment: But I still get : use of unresolved identifier JSONEnconding when I use
Alamofire.request("www.myUrl", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEnconding.default, headers: headers)
                        .responseJSON()

Comment: Oh there was a typo in your answer I didnt se JSONEncoding/JSONEnconding

Answer (score 2):

What type is `parameters`? It has to be at least `[:]` - like:

`Alamofire.request(url: myUrl, method: .put, parameters: [:], encoding: JSONEnconding.default, headers: myHeaders)`

Comment: Like this: let parameters: [String: AnyObject]

Comment: But I still get : use of unresolved identifier JSONEnconding when I use
Alamofire.request("www.myUrl", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEnconding.default, headers: headers)
                        .responseJSON()

Comment: Oh there was a typo in your answer I didnt se JSONEncoding/JSONEnconding

Answer (score 1):

I broke mind into URLRequest and then just the Alamofire call. Nothing I found worked except breaking it up. I'm using Swift 3 and XCode 8.2.1 and I believe this is swift's sourceKit getting an object wrong.

this

```
    Alamofire.request(url:treeURL!, method: .get, parameters: [:], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["Authorization" : app.getToken()])
```

became this:

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: treeURL!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["Authorization" : app.getToken()]
    Alamofire.request(request as URLRequestConvertible)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Alamofire.request( "http://....", method: .put , parameters: parameters, encoding:  JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON{
            response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                //some code
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is not helpful.